# Ajax , xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName() don't worked on chrome and IE but worked on firefox

Tags: ajax, xml, google-chrome, servlets

I'm a ajax beginner. I'm trying to write a simple search suggestion. When I use firefox test It worked, but when I use chrome  I got that:  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null**

I wrote this on the callback function

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var data = xhr.responseXML;
        var x = data.getElementsByTagName("suggestion");
        var div = document.getElementById("suggest")
        div.innerHTML = "";
        showSuggest();
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            var result= x[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
            div.innerHTML += "<div id='sResult' onmouseover='over(this)' onmouseout='out(this)' onclick='replace(this)' >"
                + result+ "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

and this on Servlet doGet method:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("test/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");

        //get suggestion from  db
        List<KeyWord> kw = SearchService.suggest(keyword);
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>");
        pw.write("<suggestions>");
        for(KeyWord k:kw){
            pw.write("<suggestion>");
            pw.write(k.getContent());
            pw.write("</suggestion>");
        }
        pw.write("</suggestions>");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
```

Comment: Java has APIs to create well-formed XML so consider to use them instead of doing string concatenation. If `k.getContent()` contains an ampersand `&` or a less-than sign `<` then your response is not well-formed XML. Whether that is the reason for the error I don't know, press F12 in Chrome or IE to open the developer tools and check the net console for the HTTP response headers and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `response.setContentType("test/xml;charset=UTF-8");` is not a typo in your post then correct it to say `response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");` and hopefully IE and Chrome populate `responseXML`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this

```
var x = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("suggestion");
```

instead of

```
var x = data.getElementsByTagName("suggestion");
```

?

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.

Comment: thanks for the comment - I'll make sure I learn from this, and apply your recommendation to future posts.

Comment: My pleasure :-) Until then, [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370) could be also useful for you.

Comment: @peter - many thanks - I was born in England.  I appreciate you're only trying to help ;)